# How do actions work with routes for rendered views?

Tags: ember.js

Can someone tell me why "Action" does not work here?  Has it got to do with my route?
`{{#linkTo "content.friend" this}}`

http://jsbin.com/EtOjuTe/17

http://jsbin.com/EtOjuTe/19 (Here is the version with it uncommented and thus no output)

Thank you.

Comment: The `{{link-to}}` is to perform transition to the specified route, this is used to change pages, to run some code when some event is triggered you need to use the `{{action}}`. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `linkTo` is the name of the route that you want to link to.  You don't have a route called `content.friend`, so Ember fails when trying to build the link.

I would expect that you would want to use `contact.friend`, but that's not working either.  I think this is due to the jsbin being set up with an old version of Ember.  I can get it to at least build the link by using just `friend`.  Since the `friend` route is nested under `contact` that means Ember needs two models to be involved in the link.

Since the contact is attached to the friend model as `who`, you can do this:

```
{{#linkTo "friend" who this}}
```

That gets the link to build, but the id for `contact` is `undefined`.  Again I suspect that an old version of Ember is at fault.

Here's the Ember docs about linking to routes with multiple dynamic segments.  http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_example-for-multiple-segments

Here's a semi working jsbin : http://jsbin.com/OdoHaGi/1/edit